# Python nested argparse issues

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to get this to work

script.py command onesubcommand mabyanotherone [something] [--optional stuff]

This currenlty works with script.py command -h and it shows that command got a set of subcommands, and etc command subcommand -h shows it got a set of required options and optional.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some commands :D.')
mainsubparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

###

# Arg (sub)command <sub>
parser_list = mainsubparsers.add_parser('command', help='List different things, see command -h')
subparsers = parser_list.add_subparsers()

# Arg (sub)command > subcommand (amount)
parser_subcommand = subparsers.add_parser('subcommand')
parser_subcommand.add_argument('-a', '--amount', type=int, help='Amount to list', default=5)

###

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then I'm trying to get this to work

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  if args.parser_command:

      ###

      elif args.parser_command.subcommand:
        # Do stuff

      ###
```

but throws

```
py script.py command subcommand
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 178, in <module>
    if args.parser_command:
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'parser_command'
```

So I tried to add this to the parser part

```
def c_command:
  print(args)


parser_command = mainsubparsers.add_parser('command', help='List different things,see command -h')
subparsers = parser_command.add_subparsers()
parser_command.set_defaults(func=c_command)

###

args.func(args)
```

the function gets triggered but I don't see how I can get the subcommand out and it's parameters, etc args.command throws namespace.

How do I solve this or how do I do this the correct way?

I just want nested commands with options.

Comment: your error says `elif args.parser_command:` but there is no `elif` in your example code. Please ensure you are posting code and errors that go together.

Comment: Edited to match the error. Just a mismatch when writing this down. (Could not copypaste)

Comment: Your options are named `command` and `subcommand` not `parser_command` and `parser_subcommand` (and that `elif` code is  invalid python).

Comment: changed to if args.command and this is the output "AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'command".
How is elif invalid python?

Comment: The indentation, and the lack of other related code at that indentation.

Comment: Okey didn't make myself clear I guess. There are more code before it, but it's not relevant, etc a "If False:" since I was testing something. But thats not the issue, the issue is argparse part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with the nesting.  It's with basic `subparsers` definition.

Look at the `namespace`, the `args` object created by `parse_args`:

```
In [4]: parser.parse_args(['command'])
Out[4]: Namespace()
In [5]: parser.parse_args(['command','subcommand'])
Out[5]: Namespace(amount=5)
```

A command like: `mainsubparsers = parser.add_subparsers()` doesn't save any indication of what the command was.  `Out[5]` has an attribute because of the `parser_subcommand.add_argument...`, and value is the default.

`In[4]` is possible with Py3.  In Py2 is will raise an error, because subparsers are required (that's a bug in Py3 version).

If I add a `dest` parameter to each `add_subparsers` (as discussed in the docs) I get

```
In [8]: parser.parse_args(['command','subcommand'])
Out[8]: Namespace(amount=5, cmd='command', subcmd='subcommand')
```

With this then `args.cmd` and `args.subcmd` can be referenced.

The docs also show how `set_defaults` can be used to define other attributes selectively, including ones with object values.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, I will try this out.

Comment: Correct way to do it or not, this works perfectly. Thanks a lot, I have used the whole day to get this to work.